# Fill HTML with JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm sure this is an easy one but i have just no idea how to make this happen. I got a PHP file which reads some data from a MySQL database and return the data in a JSON format.
Now i am looking for a way to put this data in HTML, so that "data_from_json" is replaced with "18.5" (in this case).
Any help is appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="bs-example bs-example-type">
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Temperature</td>
            <td align="right"> "data_from_json" </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSON content:

```
[[18.5]]
```

Comment: Show us your JSON data.

Comment: Read this [Display json in html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283003/display-json-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your html file is different and your php script file is different,

you can simply make an ajax request to the php script and consume its return type, then inside the success event of the ajax request, you can set the required td's `innerText`
i.e. in your html page, at the end of the body tag, you can create a script like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        //variables
        var scriptToExecute="myDbReader.php";//php script

        //any data that you might want to send to the php script.
        var data ='anyData='+anyValue; 

        //call ajax function 
        makeAjaxRequest(scriptToExecute,data,callBack);
        function callBack(data){
            $('#td').html(data);
        }
</script>
```

where td is the id of the td, you want to set text of and makeAjaxRequest is a simple function that performs ajax request via traditional XHR or modern jQuery's ajax i.e.

```
function makeAjaxRequest(url,data,_callBack,_failure){
    $.ajax({
       url:url,
       datatype:"application/json",
       type:'get',
       data: data, 
       success:function(data){
           _callBack(data);
       },
       error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          if(!_failure){
            console.log(errorThrown);
          }
          else
          {
            _failure(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown);
          }
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery.Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) to call the PHP page and load the data it returns.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data_to_load.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8;',
        success: function (data) {
            //Use data.d to access the JSON object that is returned.
        },
        error: function (ajaxrequest) {
            //Use ajaxrequest.responseText to access the error that is returned.
        }
    })
```

You can also view a Pure Javascript Ajax example [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript/).

Answer (score 0):

could you try `<td align="right"> "<?php echo $data_from_json[0][0] ?>" </td>`. Update your php variable `data_from_json` to `$data_from_json`.

I am a new php guy. this is just a suggestion.

Comment: I think technically this will work, not sure, but even if it does it is considerably less robust than the ajax approaches in other answers so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: if using ajax. I agree with using `$('td').eq(1).text(data)` after calling the service. but I think the question is that asker wanna know how to render in his php code.